# How can I set display resolution to 3840x2160 with Intel Graphics 3000?

Tags: hdmi, 4k-resolution, xrandr

My system is Debian Linux. My new 4k UHD display only uses 1920x1080 by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 19
# 3840x2160 18.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 41.48 kHz; pclk: 205.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_19.00"  205.75  3840 4008 4400 4960  2160 2163 2168 2186 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_19.00"  205.75  3840 4008 4400 4960  2160 2163 2168 2186 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "3840x2160_19.00"
```

Then I can select 3840x2160 in display settings.
Higher refresh rates don't seem to work, so things are not displayed very smoothly, especially mouse pointer and movies.

**Even better:**

Download http://www.riscosports.co.uk/cvt.zip

(Compile source code with `gcc -o cvt -lm cvt.c`)

Calculate the modeline with

```
$ ./cvt  3840 2160 24 -r -x

  # 3840x2160 @ 24.00 Hz Reduced Blank (CVT)
  #   field rate 24.00 Hz; hsync: 52.44 kHz; pclk: 209.75 MHz
  Modeline "3840x2160_24.00_rb"  209.75  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2185  +HSync -Vsync
```

Then I can select 3840x2160 at 24Hz in display settings.

I filed a bug for Debian cvt not supporting reduced blank at refresh rates other than multiples of 60Hz: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899066